# Linking assembly function .asm to c++ project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, function, assembly, linker, masm

I've created in windows c++ project in Visual Studio to learn how to write asm functions. 
So in my project I've got hello.asm with this simple code:

```
.686
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK
.DATA 
.CODE

hello PROC
xor eax,eax
ret 
hello ENDP

END
```

and asm_test.cpp with main function like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" void hello();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

So in general ml.exe doesnt have any problem compiling asm file to hello.obj
but hello() function doesnt' know where should it be taken from. And here is what compiler tells me.

```
1>------ Построение начато: проект: asm_test, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assembling hello.asm...
1>asm_test.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _hello в функции _wmain
1>G:\renderer\asm_test\Debug\asm_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Sorry, it's on russion, but it's clear that it can not find hello function

Answer (score 1):

change `hello` to be `_hello` plz. for your `hello.asm`, it should be:

```
.686
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK
.DATA 
.CODE

_hello PROC
xor eax,eax
ret 
_hello ENDP

END
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked, although it's still not obvious for me why it should be like that. Can you provide a small explanation?

Comment: @Antiusninja Though your code reference function `hello` in `main` as `hello()`, the compiler convert it to be `_hello()`, that's why the linker can not find the symbol.